# Do sound waves deflect off of a charged plate in ion-filled liquid?

Tags: waves, acoustics, ions

Suppose there is a small tank of water filled with charged particles, and a sound wave is being transmitted through it.  If a metal plate was placed in the tank and a voltage applied to the plate, would voltage deflect the sound waves in the water at all?

My reason for wondering is that if the water contains ions, and ions are affected by voltage, perhaps the ions in the water would be attracted/repelled by the charged plate and affect the propagation of the wave.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: I assume you mean reflect instead of deflect. Why would a flow of current have any effect on the propagation of sound?

Comment: My understanding is that sound is a traveling wave through a medium, so water molecules are bumping into each other as the wave travels.  Is that correct?  If there are charges in the water that are bumping around as well, and charges experience a force from nearby voltages, I'm wondering if the nearby charges in the water will experience a change in behavior, and transmit that change to the traveling wave.

Comment: Not familiar with the subject, but a lot of material properties in ionic solutions are affected by _ionic strength_, which produces electrostriction. Try googling "ionic strength sound water", or "electrostriction sound water" and combinations thereof.

Comment: My very quick search produced this ref. https://books.google.com/books?id=Fydma-RSBHAC&pg=PA112&lpg=PA112&dq=sound+ionic+strength+water&source=bl&ots=rpRdwRcRTX&sig=x5rbUfkp3hIod9AAx3Xjr7hFqDY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf7P6z8rrOAhVBwiYKHZ7uCvcQ6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=sound%20ionic%20strength%20water&f=false, which happens to state that "The reduction in volume by electrostriction leads to much greater attenuation of sound in the ocean, compared to the situation in fresh water". Stands to mind your idea may hold water after all, pun intended :)

Comment: Try looking at the following paper [http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016MNRAS.458.4400B](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016MNRAS.458.4400B).  Paul shows that if the collision rate is high enough and ionization state low enough, then you can get a sort of "clumping" of neutral particles around ions, thus creating effectively very heavy ions.  It's a form of mass-loading that, I think, is what you are after in this question.

Comment: Granted that ions in solution will affect the physical properties of the solution and hence have some affect on the sound propagation characteristics.  However, the question was whether or not a metal plate with an applied voltage (and inducing a current flow) would deflect a sound wave.  Since sound is an elastic travelling oscillation, I don't see how a current flow would have that effect.

Comment: Ah, so I was thinking that the voltage might change how ions are distributed the solution, and might therefore affect the sound wave.  I'm curious about the question: when the voltage is switched on and then off, will there be a difference in the sound wave because of the way the charges are distributed?

Comment: The effect you are suggesting would be an electro-acoustic phenomena.  Here is a link that I found that might be of interest. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroacoustic_phenomena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets take your question in two parts,
1) Will a sound wave be reflected (deflected) off a metal plate immersed in a ionized liquid? Yes.
2) What effect will placing a charge on the metal plate have on the sound reflection?
We start by assuming the ions are positive and that we apply a negative voltage to the metal plate.  As the sound wave propagates through the liquid, the ions move up and down (perpendicular to the direction of motion). When we put a charge on the plate, the ions will experience an attractive horizontal force, which essentially causes the fluid to move towards the plate (independent of the sound).  This is equivalent to having a pump move the liquid at a given velocity, which will have no effect on the sound wave.  If we apply a varying voltage instead, then you end up with the sound wave "modulated" at the varying voltage frequency.

Comment: Ah, so a changing voltage will affect the sound wave.  That's exactly what I was wondering.  Thanks!